# Is it possible to configure <div> to overflow parent <td> element rather than expand id?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with the following structure:

```
<table>
  <tr> <td> COL 1 </td> <td> COL 2 <td> <td> COL 3 </td> </tr>
  <tr> <td colspan=999> <div> LONG VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT </div> </td> </tr>
</table>
```

It is possible to assign some set of CSS attribute to the DIV in the second row such that it doesn't expand the width of the table, but instead overflows the boundaries of table. Basically, I want to the width of the table to be determined by the contents of the first row.

Comment: Well, if I set it to 3, then i'd have to change it whenever the number of columns in the other row changes. So I just set to something very large to make sure I don't ever have to change it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
td div { position:absolute }
```

You can then style the DIV to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Give the table a width. If that isn't enough, give the div one too.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option. I want the size of the table to be determined by the size of the columns in another row. These other columns need to be as wide as necessary.

Answer (score -1):

If i get ur question right ill suggest u
Why use table for this.

 Use CSS with floats and display it as table row or columns as required.